# How to enable outline in wordpress block editor gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I started using wordpress block editor today and one thing is really driving me crazy, i can't figure out how to enable outlines on hovering not clicking on blocks. I have grouped blocks and it's extremely annoying to guess what block i'm clicking on.

Answer (score 0):

There's disagreement among some developers and users whether or not the current focused block should be outlined or highlighted; and is discussed in this [this github issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/23892). You can share your opinion in there.

Meanwhile, there's also the [highlight-blocks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/highlight-blocks/) plugin that adds this feature as well.